# Not able to get MongoDB Cookbook "Querying for a Date Range" work with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, datetime, mongoose

I have been trying to get a node.js / mongoose query using a date range in an application and it has not worked. So, I took [the code from the Mongo DB cookbook for date range]: http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/ and put it into a simple node.js application to see if I could get that to work (with no success).

Here is the code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/tb');

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  title: String,
  author: String,
  content: String,
  created_on: Date
});

Post = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);

var newPost = new Post({
    "title" : "A blog post",
    "author" : "Mike",
    "content" : "...",
    "created_on" : new Date()
});

Post.remove({},
  function(err) {
    console.log("cleared out Posts...");
    newPost.save( function (err, record) {
       console.log("record saved: " + record);
       var start = new Date(2013, 7, 1);
       var end = new Date(2013, 8, 1);

       Post.find({ },
         function( err, result_set1) {
           console.log("result without date query: " + JSON.stringify(result_set1));
           Post.find({created_on: { $gte: start, $lt: end }},
             function( err, result_set2) {
               console.log("result with date query: " + JSON.stringify(result_set2));
               });
           });
        });
    });
```

And here are the results. When I don't pass date filters, I get the results, but when I put in the date filters I don't get results back. I really appreciate help in figuring this out.

```
cleared out Posts...
record saved: { __v: 0,
  title: 'A blog post',
  author: 'Mike',
  content: '...',
  created_on: Fri Jul 26 2013 23:07:59 GMT+0000 (UTC),
  _id: 51f3014f02fee3c438000001 }
result without date query: [{"title":"A blog post","author":"Mike","content":"...","created_on":"2013-07-26T23:07:59.136Z","_id":"51f3014f02fee3c438000001","__v":0}]
result with date query: []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to feel silly about this, but the month argument when constructing a `Date` object like you have there is zero-based.

```
new Date(2013, 7, 1)
Thu Aug 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT)
```

Your months are off by one (too high). Direct your rage at Brendan Eich.

Comment: Nice! I figured it might be something simple. You saved me a lot of time nonetheless. Much appreciated!